# How to get number of unused/used connection in nodejs mysql connection pool?

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection-pooling

I am using nodejs connection pooling, with npm's "mysql" module.
While creating a pool I have specified the connectionLimit as 100.
I would like to know how many of my connections are used/unused from the pool at runtime.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By looking at [the source code here](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/lib/Pool.js#L10), it appears that you can look at:

```
pool.config.connectionLimit     // passed in max size of the pool
pool._freeConnections.length    // number of free connections awaiting use
pool._allConnections.length     // number of connections currently created, including ones in use
pool._acquiringConnections.length // number of connections in the process of being acquired
```

Note: New connections are created as needed up to the max size of the pool so `_freeConnections.length` could be zero, but there are many more connections in the limit so the next time `.getConnection()` is called, it will create a new connection.